# boostrap 4 card footer does not display properly (using flex)

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I have this card footer :

```
<div class="card text-center">
<!-- CODE FOR card-header, card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

                    <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                    <i class="fas fa-briefcase fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>


                    <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-info btn-sm">
                    <i class="fas fa-comments fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>


                    <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-success btn-sm">
                    <i class="fas fa-user fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>


                    <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-warning btn-sm">
                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-success btn-sm">
                    <i class="fas fa-check fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that it does not display properly on iphone 7 (using chrome on it).

I have this display on the iphone :

[image]

What is weird is that it shows correctly on chrome desktop using the "toggle device toolbar" (to see a preview of the card on iphone 7, but on the desktop chrome) :

[image]

But using the same tool, it does not show properly on iphone 5 (on desktop chrome again) :

[image]

Thanks in advance for helping me !

Comment: Try adding `position: absolute` to your card-footer.

Comment: this solution does not work. the layout is totally broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be some hit and try to get the padding correct, but you would need to tinker around with the left margin here: `.card-link+.card-link { margin-left: 4% !important;}`
to get the best effect on your iPhone.

```css
.card-link+.card-link {
  margin-left: 4% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ' crossorigin='anonymous'>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Card Header and Footer</h2>
  <div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-header">Demo Header</div>
    <div class="card-body">Demo Content</div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

        <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-primary btn-sm">
          <i class="fas fa-briefcase fa-2x"></i>
        </a>


        <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-info btn-sm">
          <i class="fas fa-comments fa-2x"></i>
        </a>


        <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-success btn-sm">
          <i class="fas fa-user fa-2x"></i>
        </a>


        <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-warning btn-sm">
          <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x"></i>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="card-link btn btn-success btn-sm">
          <i class="fas fa-check fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```